Excel needing a scrollable multicolumn table able to be resized vertically not reference to other cells but able to be populated manually
I have a worksheet populated vertically as such
Grp = Grouping
ob = observation
att = attribute
ssatt1 = session attribute
Grp#    Grp object    Ob att1     Ob att2        ssatt1  ssatt2  ssatt3
1       object1       ob1 att1    ob1 att2       ses'n1 att 1  att2  att3
1       object2       ob2 att1    ob2 att2       ses'n2 att 1  att2  att3
...
1       objectn       obn att1    obn att2       ses'n att 1  att2  att3

essentially there are n number of objects(typically from 1 to 40) being observed and thus listed in rows of first 4 columns   and then the number of times those objects are being observed (ie sessions from above) can range from 1 to x  (realistically max out around 40 but only want that list of sessions to exist in their own sheet that is bounded by the number of columns in that session for the width eg. attribute1 2 and 3   and the height of the session list to go no more than the height of the number of objects but if there are only 4 objects but say 10 sessions then it needs to be scrollable...
Yes I understand I can create a scrolling list but that list will be populated from data from another list perhaps on a different sheet.  I really want to be able to populate the session list dynamically on the main sheet here and to be able to insert rows when new sessions are done and need to be recorded. so ultimately i need to have a user defined sheet object inserted into the spreadsheet so it can be dynamically populated.
I have looked high and low and tried this and that but dont see a workflow or solution like in word being able to insert a table and resize the table on demand.
Thank you for any insight you can provide.
